# login service can't seem to read php file

Tags: php, angularjs

my angularjs login service can't seem to read my login php file because it lets the user to be logged with wrong credentials. please help me. thanks in advance.

this is my login php file

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
mysqli_select_db($con, "motor_pool");

$user = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

$Username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $user->Username);
$Password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, md5($user->Password));

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username='$Username' AND                  
Password='$Password'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
session_start();
$_SESSION['uid'] = uniqid('auth_');
print $_SESSION['uid'];
}else {
echo "no";
}
?>
```

and this is my login service file

```
'use strict';
angular.module('motorApp')
.factory('loginService', ['$http', '$location', 'sessionService',  
     function($http, $location, sessionService) {
         return {
             login: function(data, scope) {
                 var $promise = $http.post('database/login.php', data);
                 $promise.then(function(msg) {
                     var uid = msg.data;
                     if(uid) {
                         sessionService.set('uid', uid);
                         $location.path('/dashboard');
                     } else {
                         $scope.msgtxt = 'incorrect info';
                         $location.path('/login');
                     }
                 });
             }
         }
     }
 ]);
```

this is my login mark up

```
 <div class="w3-group">
     <label class="w3-label w3-text-black">User Name</label>
     <input class="w3-input w3-border w3-round" type="text"    style="width:100%" name="Username" ng-model="user.Username" required="">
 </div>
 <div class="w3-group">
     <label class="w3-label w3-text-black">Password</label>
     <input class="w3-input w3-border w3-round" name="Password" type="password" style="width:100%" required="" ng-model="user.Password">
 </div>
 <div class="w3-center">
     <input type="button" name="button" class="w3-btn-block w3-red btnlog" ng-click="login(user)" value="LOGIN">
 </div>
```

Comment: what does your login php file actually do, other than querying the users table and not doing anything with the result?

Comment: my php file's job is just to check  an existing data that matches the users inputted username and password. if there is,then the user can access the home page

Comment: is the bit that checks excluded from your code pasting above or is it not yet implemented?  Because the snippet above seems to serve no purpose, other than creating a session regardless of user input.

Comment: please see my updated code..

Comment: Yep that's an improvement @jean, you might need to update your login service file though, as it's just checking to see if there's a response from the ajax call, and if the php script returns "no" on a false login, that's still a response :)

Comment: do you have any idea on what's wrong with my login service?

Answer (score 1):

In login.php you are setting a $_SESSION['uid'] regardless of whether the user is authenticated or not.

You need something like:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {  //found an authenticated user
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['uid'] = uniqid('auth_');
   //print $_SESSION['uid'];
   //now redirect to the first authenticated page of your site
   header("Location: nextPage.php");  //or you can do a url 
   exit;
} else { //user wasn't found
//user wasn't found and present error message or error message page
}
```

Note at the start of nextPage.php, you should check for the set session and if not valid (i.e. not a valid user who browsed there by chance), send that user somewhere else, or at least prevent the rest of the script running.

Comment: the code worked for blocking users with wrong credentials, but..it doesn't let me to login now

Comment: After success, you will need to redirect a valid user to the opening page of your site. I've edited my answer above.

Comment: okay but redirecting after success is supposed to be the job of my login service file.

Comment: and by the way, the correct credentials thati inputted are not recognized by the php file, it goes directly to the else condition w/c is echo "no"

Comment: Hi, what do you want to achieve in the login.php file? The way it originally read, was that you were getting the user and password, checking it against a db, and then setting a session. In that case, assuming the credentials are in the db, the login service is unnecessary, just set the form action of the html page to login.php